# kotlinc equivalent for --patch-module from javac

Tags: kotlin, java-9, java-module, java-platform-module-system, kotlinc

Does `kotlinc` have an equivalent option for `javac`'s `--patch-module`?

e.g., `-Xmodule-path=` is the `kotlinc` equivalent option for `--module-path` from `javac`, but I haven't yet found an equivalent for `--patch-module`.

Comment: Though I am not a Kotlin user, yet why would you require that? Since even the [JEP-261](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/261#Patching-module-content) highlights the use of `--patch-module` in production is discouraged. Also, with `kotlinc-jvm 1.2.61` the command `kotlinc -X -help` doesn't list any specific option for patching either.

Comment: Because, there are times when it's necessary. e.g, if you have kotlin test code that must access the internals of a module to test it.